# Can't initialize Struct with Closure in its impl block

Tags: rust, struct, closures, coercion

#### (See Bottom For Addendum)

Let's say I defined the following Struct:

```
struct Test<F>
where
    F: Fn()
{
    func: F
}
```

I then write a constructor:

```
impl<F> Test<F>
where
    F: Fn()
{
    pub fn new_1(func: F) -> Self {
        Self {
            func
        }
    }
}
```

I run `main()` with `new_1()`:

```
fn main() {
    Test::new_1(|| println!("oy"));
}
```

and the program compiles just fine.

So I decided to get risky.

I add this constructor:

```
impl<F> Test<F>
where
    F: Fn()
{
    pub fn new_2() -> Self {
        Self { 
            func: || println!("oy") 
        }
    }  
}
```

and got the following error:

```
note: expected type parameter `F` found closure `[closure@src\mat_test.rs:23:22: 23:39]`
help: every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `F`
```

I wasn't sure why Rust couldn't coerce this closure into `F: Fn()` this time as it could before, so I tried another constructor:

```
impl<F> Test<F>
where
    F: Fn()
{
    pub fn new_3() -> Self {
        Self::new_1(|| println!("oy"))
    }
}
```

which yielded the same error.

Why is it that I can initialize `Test` using a Closure only if the Closure is defined outside its `impl` block? What causes this behavior?

## Addendum

This whole context, in reality, takes place inside of trait definition, but it seems that the `impl trait` return is not yet supported by traits. How could I go about implementing it in this case?

Comment: The caller determines what concrete type `F` is, and it cannot be the type of the closure that you're returning.  Give those functions the return type `Test<impl Fn()>` instead of `Self`, and instantiate with `Test` instead of `Self`, then it should work okay.

Comment: Your addendum makes things a bit more complex: you will need an associated type e.g. `type Instance = Test<fn()>; fn new() -> Self::Instance { ... }` etc.  However, while `fn()` will work in your given examples because the "closures" are non-capturing and can be coerced to function pointers, a more explicit type parameter will be required if the closure actually captures some environment... in that case, it's probably best to define your own trait for the type parameter and implement it for a named struct that you define for the captured environment.

Comment: Example: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6fa1285d694ca3c6498ec267af7ef4a7).

Comment: FYI, what's coming down the line with the GAT and RPITIT features, is much more directly what you're after: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=389198193372df3713a517c2c7748cc5).

Comment: Thanks again, I'll likely use fn for now, but thanks for the heads up